# Change Date to friendly format in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to change the date of launch time for EC2 instances in AWS to something more friendly using Python 3.

The error that I'm getting says:

```
datetime(launch_time)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

My program is doing this:

```
import boto3
import time
import datetime

instance_id = 'i-024b3382f94bce588'
instance = ec2.describe_instances(
    InstanceIds=[instance_id]
)['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]
launch_time = instance['LaunchTime']
datetime(launch_time)
launch_time_friendly = launch_time.strftime("%B %d %Y")
print("Server was launched at: ", launch_time_friendly)
```

How can I get the time the instances were created into a user friendly format?

Comment: `from datetime import datetime`

Answer (score 2):

There is both a `datetime` module *and* a `datetime` class. You are attempting to call the module:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime(2019, 3, 1)  # This will break!
```

Instead, you need to either import the class *from* the module:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime(2019, 3, 1)  # Okay!
```

... or import the module and reference the class:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1)  # Good!
```